# Google Cloud - Connect to postgresql database in same project with python

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine

**tl;dr:**
How do I connect to a postgres db from a gce instance in the same "project" without granting IP access to `35.185.*`

========

Hello,

I have a very simple test script which works locally:

```
print "importing"
import pandas as  pd
import urllib
import json
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
print "done importing"
conn_string = 'postgresql://my_user:my_pass@ip.of.my.db/postgres'
print "connecting"
engine = create_engine(conn_string, echo=True)
print "engine created"
engine.connect()
print "engine connected"

print "getting data"
data=json.loads(urllib.urlopen("http://ip.jsontest.com").read())
df=pd.DataFrame([data])
print "data retrieved"
df.to_sql('insert_test',engine, index=False, schema='public', chunksize=500,
                                  if_exists='append')
```

Now, this works because I have explicitly granted access to the db for my IP:
[image]

My output is:

```
importing
done importing
connecting
engine created
2017-04-14 10:17:38,319 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
2017-04-14 10:17:38,323 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,381 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
2017-04-14 10:17:38,385 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,440 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2017-04-14 10:17:38,447 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,483 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2017-04-14 10:17:38,490 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,568 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2017-04-14 10:17:38,575 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
engine connected
getting data
data retrieved
2017-04-14 10:17:38,750 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where n.nspname=%(schema)s and relname=%(name)s
2017-04-14 10:17:38,753 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'name': u'insert_test', 'schema': u'public'}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,832 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-04-14 10:17:38,841 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO public.insert_test (ip) VALUES (%(ip)s)
2017-04-14 10:17:38,848 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'ip': u'my_local_ip'}
2017-04-14 10:17:38,903 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

When I move this script to my gce instance and run it with:

```
$ python hello_db.py
```

my output is the following:

```
 File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "ip.of.my.db" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Both the DB and the compute engine instance are part of the same "project".

I can see my instance IP is `35.185.foo.blah.whatever` I know the Ip because I ran:

```
wget "http://ip.jsontest.com"
```

Given the IP of my instance will likely be dynamic as I launch many instances to distribute tasks and use the cloud to compute stuff - how do I grant access for all of these instances?

Granting `35.185.*` seems unsafe because what if someone else on gce tries to get into my DB?

I am new to this and maybe I am missing something - but I assumed my "project" would be able to access all of the other assets without issue. I am sure there is a great reason this is not the case, but it is lost on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/) was the documentation that I needed to read to solve this problem.